# Replace Qtip plugin with Tooltipster

Tags: javascript, tooltip, qtip, tooltipster

My existing Qtip function in a js file looks as below

```
function displayToolTip(element, costPriceToolTip, classNames, eventToShow) {
    var tooltipClassNames = classNames + ' ui-tooltip ui-tooltip-light';
    $global(element).qtip({
        content: costPriceToolTip,
        show: eventToShow,
        hide: 'mouseout',
        style: {
            classes: tooltipClassNames,
            tip: true
        },
        position: {
            at: 'top center',
            my: 'bottom center'
        },
        adjust: {
            method: 'shift flip'
        }
    });
}
```

I am rewriting this function using tooltipster by linking all the tooltipster files to this in the related jsp

```
<caching:javascript src="/js/login-to-panel.js"/>
<style type="text/css">
    <caching:cssImport fileName="/css/tooltipster.bundle.css"/>
    <caching:cssImport fileName="/css/tooltipster-sideTip-borderless.min.css"/>
</style>
```

and modifying the function as below.

```
function displayToolTip(element, costPriceToolTip, classNames, eventToShow) {
    $global(element).tooltipster({
        content: costPriceToolTip,
        trigger: eventToShow,
        theme: 'tooltipster-borderless',
        position: 'top-center',
        side: 'bottom'
    });
}
```

This does not work. Can someone help me with this

Comment: I think there is some issue with $global cause similar function is also not supported by tooltipster.